# Updating Obsolete .net commands with Xamarin

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I am building the following [Xamarin](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB/) example, to demo some AWS Cogneto functionality. This method, throws the following error about obsolescence. However, when I try to replace that line, I get an error about the `{` following the top line, saying it was unexpected? What should I replace the top line with, to keep the same functionality, just enabling it to work with the new versions of xamarin.forms.

```
login.LogInWithReadPermissions(readPermissions.ToArray(), delegate(LoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
    }
    else if (result.IsCancelled)
    {
        App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
    }
    else
    {
        var accessToken = result.Token;
        App.OnFacebookAuthSuccess(accessToken.TokenString);
    }
});
```

> Warning CS0618: `Facebook.LoginKit.LoginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions(string[], Facebook.LoginKit.LoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)` is obsolete: Use `LogInWithReadPermissions (string[], UIViewController, LoginManagerRequestTokenHandler) method instead` (CS0618) (Gas_Sense.iOS)

Comment: The new method just introduces a ViewController parameter between the two existing  parameters.  Have you tried passing a reference to the current ViewController?

Comment: I tried passing view controller but its still failing. I posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169856/xamarin-issue-with-latest-fb-api?noredirect=1#comment65683536_39169856). Can you please look into it and advice?