# Xamarin: Issue with latest FB API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Latest FB login API has three parameters

```
public unsafe virtual void LogInWithReadPermissions (string[] permissions, UIViewController fromViewController, [BlockProxy (typeof(Trampolines.NIDLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler))] LoginManagerRequestTokenHandler handler)
```

I am using MVVMCross. For fb login, I tried created an instance of the view i am in, and pass it as a parameter for LogInWithReadPermissions()

**VIEWMODEL:**

```
private async void DoFacebookSignIn()
        {
            try 
            {               
                await facebookService. Login();
                DoAutoLogin();
            }
}
```

**SERVICE:**

```
private readonly string[] permitions = new string[] { "email", "public_profile" };    
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task LogIn()
            {
    LoginManager.LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync (permitions);

                LoginManagerLoginResult result = await LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync();

                if (result.IsCancelled)
                {
                    ServiceFactory.UserMessageService.ShowToast("Facebook login is canceled");
                }
            }

        private Task<LoginManagerLoginResult> LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync()
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<LoginManagerLoginResult> ();
                LoginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions (permitions,null, (LoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error) =>
                {
                    if(error.IsNotNull ())
                    {
                        tcs.SetException (new IosErrorException(error));
                    } else 
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult (result);
                    }
                });

                return tcs.Task;
            }
```

But its failing, Do i need to pass view info from Viewmodel, when I am calling this func? How to pass view instance from view model ? Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

It's failing at the service:

func `LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync()` 
line3: `(LoginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions...)`

without giving any error. Its just crashing.
The Facebook API version: "Xamarin.Facebook.iOS" version="4.13.1"

**UPDATE**
Removed unused code.

Comment: You should be very careful of `async void` if they aren't for event handlers. Secondly you should upload what is exactly "failing" here. Do you get an exception? Does it silently fail? etc

Also please post the exact FB API you are using whether that's a NuGet/Component/etc

Comment: I updated my question with necessary info.

Comment: Upload a `mcve` to help show what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Secondly, have you checked your device logs for more output? https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs#debug-logs-for-xamarin-apps

Comment: I already uploaded the move.. Service Log :

`Marker - Sep 15, 2016, 3:36:25 PM
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 assertiond[1331]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 15 15:36:26 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 SpringBoard[1327]: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.6DF14381-2E70-4115-AF1D-0DE483FFD3EC.launchd_sim[1310] (UIKitApplication:com.xxx.abc[0xb7eb][10566]): Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6`

Comment: `Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 SpringBoard[1327]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxx.abc[0xb7eb]' crashed.
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 assertiond[1331]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 assertiond[1331]: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 assertiond[1331]: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 15 15:36:26 abcL017833 SpringBoard[1327]: Reply Error: Connection interrupted`

Comment: Where is FBSign located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

The code was fine I just needed to 'Whitelist Facebook Servers for Network Requests' by adding

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

If you're recompiling with iOS SDK 9.0, add the following to your application's plist if you're using a version of the SDK v4.5 or older:

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>    
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
If you're using Facebook.MessengerShareKit from versions older than the v4.6 release, also add:

<string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
<string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
<string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
If you're using v4.6.0 of the SDK, you only need to add:

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

As mentioned in Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios).

Comment: Can you tell me what FBSign does in the original post? How does it get the view controller :)

Comment: @LamonteCristo, It was a random viewcontroller so that I could pass in LogInWithReadPermissions() function. It is not necessary, I updated the code. You can check the latest code.